# using ngModel, disabling html option default selection

Tags: html, angular, html-select

In my Angular 8 application, i am using html `option`. But i am unable to set the default option. If i am using ngModel, then the default selection is not working. After removing ngModel, default selection is working.

```
<div>
   <h4>Sort By</h4>
   <select [(ngModel)]="sort_on_approv">
   <option value="id" [selected]="true" >ID</option>
   <option value="amount">Amount</option>
   <option value="payment_method">Payment Method</option>
   <option value="mobile_number">Mobile Number</option>
   <option value="date">Date</option>
   <option value="status">Status</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

i have also tried with `[selected]="true"`.

Comment: paste your ts code.

Comment: @Gangadhar Gandi --https://github.com/ajharulabedeen/alumni/blob/dev/fontend/src/app/payment/payment-mobile/payment-mobile.component.ts

Comment: You have to set it in your `.ts` like `this.sort_on_approv = 'id';`. But it will be easier if we could see your `.ts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below,

**.html**

```
<div>
   <h4>Sort By</h4>
   <select [(ngModel)]="sort_on_approv">
   <option value="id" >ID</option>
   <option value="amount">Amount</option>
   <option value="payment_method">Payment Method</option>
   <option value="mobile_number">Mobile Number</option>
   <option value="date">Date</option>
   <option value="status">Status</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
sort_on_approv: string

ngOnInit() {
   this.sort_on_approv = 'id'; // The default value you want to select.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the select to your `default` value, you need to set your ngModel `sort_on_approv` to the value you want as default.

.ts code:
`this.sort_on_approv = 'id';`